# How to flag columns with multiple conditions in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
 ID    Date         Weekday     Public_holiday      
 1     01-01-2018   Monday      0
 2     02-01-2018   Tuesday     0
 3     03-01-2018   Wednesday   1
 4     04-01-2018   Thursday    0
 5     05-01-2018   Friday      0
 6     06-01-2018   Saturday    1
 7     07-01-2018   Sunday      0
```

I want to flag it as `0` if weekday is Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday but if there is public holiday then it should be tagged as `3`, 
`1` if weekday is `Friday` but if there is public holiday then it should be tagged as `3`,
`2` if there is a weekend but if there is public holiday on weekend then it should be tagged as `2` only

I am doing following in pandas

```
 m1 = df['Weekday'].isin(['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday'])
 m2 = df['Weekday'] == 'Friday'
 m3 = df['Public_Holiday'] == 1
 df['Flag'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], ['0','1','2'],'3')
```

My desired dataframe is

```
ID    Date         Weekday     Public_holiday   Flag   
 1     01-01-2018   Monday      0               0
 2     02-01-2018   Tuesday     0               0  
 3     03-01-2018   Wednesday   1               3 
 4     04-01-2018   Thursday    0               0
 5     05-01-2018   Friday      0               1
 6     06-01-2018   Saturday    1               2
 7     07-01-2018   Sunday      0               2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is necessary add condition for filter not `Public_holiday` chained by `AND` and for `3` chained with `OR`, also default value for weekends is not specify, so added to default value:

```
m1 = df['Weekday'].isin(['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday'])
m2 = df['Weekday'] == 'Friday'
m3 = df['Public_holiday'] == 1

df['Flag'] = np.select([m1 & ~m3, m2 & ~m3, (m1 | m2) & m3], ['0','1','3'], default='2')

print (df)
   ID        Date    Weekday  Public_holiday Flag
0   1  01-01-2018     Monday               0    0
1   2  02-01-2018    Tuesday               0    0
2   3  03-01-2018  Wednesday               1    3
3   4  04-01-2018   Thursday               0    0
4   5  05-01-2018     Friday               0    1
5   6  06-01-2018   Saturday               1    2
6   7  07-01-2018     Sunday               0    2
```

You can also define all conditions with no default:

```
m1 = df['Weekday'].isin(['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday'])
m2 = df['Weekday'] == 'Friday'
m3 = df['Public_holiday'] == 1
m4 = df['Weekday'].isin(['Saturday','Sunday'])

df['Flag'] = np.select([m1 & ~m3, (m1 | m2) & m3, m4, m2 & ~m3], ['0','3','2','1'])
```